# How do I unlock the third tier of upgrades in Hard Reset?

Tags: hard-reset

The in-game message just says "Install more upgrades".

The only information I can find online is this less than useful [note on wikia](http://hardreset.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrade_Terminal) (bold mine):

> NOTE: The last two upgrade 'trees' for both weapons and Fletcher's combat gear are 'locked out' until **a number** of earlier upgrades are purchased first.

So, specifically how many upgrades do I need to buy before they are available? Also is the threshold on total upgrades, or are there different counters for each of the three categories (CLN, N.R.G, Combat Gear)?